# How to export list to csv using PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, csv

I have a Powershell script that outputs data from all libraries in a site shown below:

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$url = "http://contoso.com"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()


function GetCheckedOutFiles($web)
{
Write-Host "Processing Web: $($web.Url)..."
        foreach ($list in ($web.Lists | ? {$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]})) {
            Write-Host "`tProcessing List: $($list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)..."
            foreach ($item in $list.CheckedOutFiles) {
                #$modifiedTime = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone
                if (!$item.Url.EndsWith(".aspx")) { continue }
                $data = @{
                    #"URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
                     "Version" = $item["Version"]
                     "Title" = $item.Title
                     #"CheckedOut By" = $item.File.CheckedOutBy.Name
                     "#Time last Modified" = $modifiedTime.UTCToLocalTime($item.File.TimeLastModified)
                }
                New-Object PSObject -Property $data
            }
            foreach ($item in $list.Items) {

                #$modifiedTime = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone

                if ($item.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") {
                    if (($list.CheckedOutFiles | where {$_.ListItemId -eq $item.ID}) -ne $null) { continue }


                    $data = @{
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
                        "Version" = $item["Version"]
                        "Library" = $item.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Title" = $item.File.Name
                        "CheckedOut By" = $item.File.CheckedOutBy.Name
                        "Time last Modified" = $modifiedTime.UTCToLocalTime($item.File.TimeLastModified)
                    }
                    New-Object PSObject -Property $data
                }
            }

        }
foreach($subWeb in $web.Webs)
{
GetCheckedOutFiles($subweb)
}
        $web.Dispose()
}



#Get-DocInventory | Out-GridView
GetCheckedOutFiles($web) | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\NewDocInventory.csv
```

In addition to outputting libraries how can I also output all lists from contoso.com? What line must I add to the script to pull lists as well? Can someone please advise?

Comment: the line foreach ($list in ($web.Lists | ? {$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]})) { is filtering out lists. Just do foreach ($list in ($web.Lists){}.

Comment: I have tried and I get error:( Sorry for the late response as I was recovering from being sick. But could you please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a much simpler script that does the trick shown below:

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
  $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl
  $web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Depts/HTG"
  foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {

    foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
      foreach($version in $item.Versions){
        $data = @{
          "Version" = $version.VersionLabel
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Item Name" = $item.File.Name
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date", "URL"
      }
    }
    $web.Dispose();
  }
}

Get-DocInventory  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\NewOutput.csv
```

This script will output all files and items from Libraries and Lists in a site.